# Leaflet draw plugin disable double Click event to finish drawing polyline

Tags: ionic-framework, leaflet, leaflet.draw

im stuck for 4 days trying to find a way to disable the dblclick event for finishing drawing of polyline using leaflet draw plugin...
any help, trick or idea would be appreciated
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could include in class `L.Draw.Polygon` new `_updateFinishHandler` function which binds this handlers. It will be something like this :

```
L.Draw.Polygon.include({
   _updateFinishHandler:function(){
    var markerCount = this._markers.length;
    if (markerCount > 1) {
        this._markers[markerCount - 1].on('click', this._finishShape, this);
    }
    if (markerCount > 2) {
        this._markers[markerCount - 2].off('click', this._finishShape, this);
    }
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but in fact im trying to disable the dblclick event for the polyline handler not the polygon handler and when i searched in "Draw.Polyline.js" i find this code :